# Is there any reference regarding the use of these extra-biblical sources in Mennonite congregations?

Tags: apocrypha, reference-request, mennonite

**Background**

A few years ago, a concern was raised by a member of a local Mennonite congregation about the use of citations from the [Shepherd of Hermas](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/shepherd-lightfoot.html). At the time, the concern was alleviated when it was mentioned that the Mennonite council endorsed its use as a secondary text.

Recently, the concern was raised again. This time the member would like a citation or reference in order to substantiate either the endorsement, repudiation, or neutrality toward this text by Mennonite Bretheren.

**Question**

Does anyone have a cite or reference that discusses whether and to what extent the following extra-biblical sources are considered appropriate for teaching and instruction for Mennonite congregations?

- Epistle of Barnabas,
- The Shepherd of Hermas
- The First Epistle of Clement to the Corinthians,

Any citation or reference either supporting or repudiating these texts from a Mennonite denomination or organization is requested.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of question we like on C.SE. Welcome and thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are always happy to have new people participate. This question is perfectly within site guidelines. In case that was a coincidence you can see the [about] page and the [help] to learn how we do things here.

Comment: Great first question, you should get a prize (if you can't tell we're a little hard pressed to find good questions from first time users so this is an event). However just a heads up that good questions usually take the longest to answer because they actually require knowledge and expertise and research! I hope you can be patient until the right person comes across this. Anybody can jut on an opinion about some general issue. If this does get buried after a little while ping one of us and we'll try to get it some extra attention.

Answer (score 3):

Having been a Mennonite for all my adult life, and attending a Mennonite Brethren church for the last 8 years or so, I have never heard of *The Shepherd of Hermas*, or any of the other books you mentioned.

However, Mennonites, and many other denominations, often use written resources in sermons, corporate worship (recitations, hymns, songs), etc, that are extra-Biblical.

The official stand of the U.S. Mennonite Brethren Church on the use of such teachings is summed up in [Article 2](http://www.usmb.org/confession-of-faith---detailed-version#Article%202) of the Confession of Faith:

> The Holy Spirit continues to make God known to individuals and the church; this revelation is always consistent with the Scriptures.

According to this, any extra-Biblical teaching which claims to be revelation of God ought to be permitted, so long as it is consistent with the Scriptures.

Comment: Note that I have not been able to find any official definition, from the MB church, of "scripture," to know whether the Apocrypha is or can be considered "scripture."  I know from experience it is not, but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Thing is, one report showed that there was a web link out there that included references to these other texts on a MB church, but the link was not saved and repeated google searches have not been able to turn it up again.

Comment: @dreftymac Have you tried the Wayback Machine (http://archive.org/web/web.php)?